# Android: Read text file under /data/data/<package_name>/files

Tags: android, file, text

I'm trying to read from a text file under /data/data/package_name/files.

This is my code:

```
private String readTxt(String fileName)
{
    String result = "", line;
    try
    {
        File f = new File(fileName);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            result += line + "\n";
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check the `fileName` value, and you have the permission to read this file or not.

Comment: thats not the point. you always have the permission to read and write files within you own package directory

Comment: ive found the problem, i forgot to give the path. it works with File f = new File(getFilesDir(), fileName);

Answer (score 0):

You should use the openFileInput Method from your application context. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput(java.lang.String)

Which will give you a InputStream to your file
Example:
final InputStream is = getApplicationContext().openFileInput(MY_FILENAME_WITHOUT_PATH);

Comment: if file was in cache folder?

Answer (score 0):

```
private String getStringFromFile(Context accessClass,String fileName){
    String result=null;
    FileInputStream fIn;
    ContextWrapper accessClassInstance=new ContextWrapper(accessClass);

    try {
        fIn = accessClassInstance.openFileInput(fileName);

        InputSource inputSource=new InputSource(fIn);
                    InputStream in = inputSource.getInputStream();

                  if (in != null) {
                 // prepare the file for reading
                      InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(in);
                      BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(input);

                 result = "";
                while (( line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
                       result += line;
                  }
                     in.close();
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File Contents ==> " + result,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 



    return result;
}
```